# customize sidebar widget container items

Tags: wordpress, widget, sidebar, menu-items

I developed a custom theme and register_sidebar in function.php to show menus on sidebar using Custom Menu (widget).
Then create a menu through Appearance-> Menu and set it in Widget's Sidebar area by using Custom Menu
Now I need to add an extra link for login page. This link

should use extra class  , which all other links/menu aren't using.
I added extra link through Appearance-> Menu but please help me to know how can I add a class for only that extra link (login)

Answer (score 0):

```
$args = array(
    'name'          => __( 'Sidebar name', 'theme_text_domain' ),
    'id'            => 'unique-sidebar-id',
    'description'   => '', 
        'class'         => 'PUT YOUR CLASS HERE', <=== here you can mention your class
    'before_widget' => '<li id="%1$s" class="widget %2$s">',
    'after_widget'  => '</li>',
    'before_title'  => '<h2 class="widgettitle">',
    'after_title'   => '</h2>' ); ?>
register_sidebar( $args );
```

[Register sidebar](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_sidebar) Refer here

Comment: Thanks for reply but this class will impact on whole menu items not the specific one , as I mentioned. I only want to use specific class for the last one link/item.